# JPA facet issue: Not able to add drivers in the "specify a driver and connection details" wizard

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using Spring Tool Suite. While adding the JPA Facet, in "specify a driver and connection details" the drivers drop down list is grayed out. Also when I go to "new driver definition", I get all wizard with all the sections grayed out and an empty jar list. [See the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Edfx.jpg)

[This is how "new driver definition" wizard looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB6NF.jpg)

Please note: I have included the user libraries(EclipseLink), tried everything else like Maven update,validate,etc.[These are the jar files included using EclipseLink.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvo3F.jpg)

Comment: Can you verify if you have the Eclipse DTP (Database Tool Platform) components installed?

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi No I hadn't. I installed it, made no difference.

Comment: What's the STS version? I installed eclipse data tools which worked. Can you update more screenshots? When you select All option, do you see a complete list of driver vendors? if not can you update the STS version?

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi I am using the Version: 3.9.3.RELEASE. The drivers list is empty (and grayed out), also the all the options to add jars etc(in new driver definition) is grayed out.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi Have included few screenshots in the original post.

Comment: I see the available driver templates section does not show up, so take a look at the DTP (eclipse data tools platform) version, it should be 1.14.1.201712071719, if not or same try to uninstall the plugin and install it again.

Comment: goto help -> about spring tool suite -> select installation details and check the version of data tools platform.  Update it or remove and re-install.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi The version of DTP is 1.14.1.201712071719

Comment: I re-installed the DTP, now somehow I can't find JPA facet in the project facets section. @VikramPalakurthi

Comment: Re-installed the JPA facets too, same problem persists.

Comment: I guess you would have to update the webtools and the eclipselink using the below url http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/ and http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/updates/ these updates should fix the dtp and eclipselink issues. You need to use help -> install new software and paste these links. But I also found out, there is not much documentation available on this one.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi Same problem persists. :/

Comment: We can to screen share to see what's happening, let me know if that works.